# Python Code Not Listing First Line in CSV File

Tags: python, csv

I was working on IMDB movie list just to list movie names, links and my ratings. Here is the code:

```
import csv
r_list = open('ratings.csv')
rd = csv.reader(r_list, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
movies = {}
for row in rd:
    movies[row[5]] = [row[0], row[8]]
print(len(movies))
```

The output is 500 but actual number is 501. It is not showing the first line. But when I do the same thing for a list that contains 6 lines in total, it counts the first line and returns '6'.
Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using a dictionary and you have row[5] which is duplicate and is replaced and thereby shortening your list by the number of duplicates (minus one) you have. You cannot have 2 keys in a dictionary that are the same. That is illegal. Python handles that silently by overwritting (replacing) the value of the key you had with the new value.

e.g.

```
data = [('rambo', 1995), ('lethal weapon', 1992), ('rambo', 1980)]
movies = {}
for row in data:
    movies[row[0]] = row[1]

print len(data) # -> 3
print len(movies) # -> 2
print movies['rambo'] # -> 1980
```

Solution is not to use the dictionary if you dont want duplicate keys to be replace each other.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was useful. The key is repeating at some point. You are right.